# Highlight Selected row is highlighting all the rows

Tags: html, css, angular, selected

I want it so when I select a row of the table, it highlights that selected row. Currently if I select a row, it highlights all the rows.
Here is what it looks like:
[image: highlighted rows]

This is the HTML code I used:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-hover table-borderless">
  <tr *ngFor="let filter of pagedFilters">
    <td [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == row}"
        (click)="highlight(row.index)">
        {{filter.viewType | filter: filterTypes }}
    </td>
    <td>
      <a><i class="oi oi-list" ></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
.highlight {
  background: green;
}
```

Finally the angular code:

```
highlight(row) {
    this.selectedRowIndex = row;
}
```

How can I get it to only highlight the selected. It also needs to un-highlight when a different one is selected.

Comment: try using $index instead of row in <td> html

Comment: Where is `*ngFor`?

Comment: can you post all the html please?

Comment: It's not clear what is row in your context. Extend example with *ngFor.

Comment: I have added the *ngFor to the html code.

Answer (score 1):

change it to below code, it will work;

```
<table class="table table-sm table-hover table-borderless">
 <tr *ngFor="let filter of pagedFilters">
  <td [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == row.index}"
    (click)="highlight(row.index)">
    {{filter.viewType | filter: filterTypes }}
  </td>
  <td>
   <a><i class="oi oi-list" ></i></a>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

hope it helps.

Comment: This solution sadly doesn't work. The application produces an error. It states that index is undefined. @MohammadHajiaghazadeh